# Pojo class to make a line chart in Android

Tags: android, json, api, charts

I would like to create a line chart (android) from data coming from Json (API) but it's a bit difficult. In the following example, I have data from 0 to 4, but if I have thousands of data, how can I do it?

```
    {
    "0": {
        "strength": 60,
        "angle": 5,
        "date": "2018-07-01T18:45:54.000Z"
    },
    "1": {
        "strength": 33,
        "angle": 52,
        "date": "2018-07-01T18:46:13.000Z"
    },
    "2": {
        "strength": 33,
        "angle": 75,
        "date": "2018-07-01T18:46:21.000Z"
    },
    "3": {
        "strength": 96,
        "angle": 63,
        "date": "2018-07-01T18:46:22.000Z"
    },
    "4": {
        "strength": 30,
        "angle": 40,
        "date": "2018-07-22T02:03:57.000Z"
    },
    "success": true
}
```

Comment: **`Its Invalid JSON`**  You can check here https://jsonlint.com/  **And better to change your response from back end side**

Comment: I'm in charge of the application only and not the API. I just edit the JSON and now is valid.

Comment: Than  ask the person who  create   that api to change response

Comment: I agree with @NileshRathod , Either backend developer should change response and return Array, instead of dynamic objects with keys, or you should use Map as parser topmost object. For LineChart use MPAndroidChart :   https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart